# Superimpose 2 images over another (background image) with precise positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 images. One is a background image which dictates the size of the div enclosing it (img {width: 100%  height:auto) which allows me to dynamically resize the div, keeping the ratio of the picture locked.

[image]

I also have 2 images that put together equal the dimensions of the background image. They are transparent, bar the black circular profile images:

[image]

I am trying to position these 2 images over the top of the background image and I simply cannot achieve this. I need them to stay fixed over the background image so when the window is resized, they resize with the background image keeping their position over the top of it (i.e. shrink with the background image). Ending up with this:

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this? Thank you in advance for any guidance.

```js
function openLink(evt, animName) {
  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("information");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(animName).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: "walkway oblique ultraBold";
  src: url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/Walkway_Oblique_UltraBold.woff?8124544898226561589") format("woff");
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

a:link {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid-container-social {
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item {
  font-family: 'walkway oblique ultraBold', arial;
  background-color: black;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#background img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#image-left img {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#image-right img {
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

.background-wrap {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 7;
}

.item_social {
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
}

.fab-flag:hover {
  color: #0099cc;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container  header-space">
  <div class="background-wrap"><br><br>
    <div id="background"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/about_us_background.png?15676093355455950193">
      <div id="image-left"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/left_image.png?17699760671222922809"></div>
      <div id="image-right"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/right_image.png?17699760671222922809"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-container">
      <div class="item1 grid-item"></div>
      <div class="item2">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubcrew');">
          <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub
            <font color="red">crew</font>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item3">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubstory');">
          <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub
            <font color="red">story</font>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item4">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubmission');">
          <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub
            <font color="red">mission</font>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item5">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubvibe');">
          <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub
            <font color="red">vibe</font>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item6">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubpromise');">
          <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub
            <font color="red">promise</font>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="item7">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubsocial');">
          <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub
            <font color="red">social</font>
          </div>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="ubcrew" class="information w3-animate-opacity">
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
      <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ubstory" class="information w3-animate-left" style="display:none">
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
      <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ubmission" class="information w3-animate-top" style="display:none">
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
      <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ubvibe" class="information w3-animate-right" style="display:none">
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
      <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ubpromise" class="information w3-animate-bottom" style="display:none">
      <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
      <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ubsocial" class="information w3-animate-bottom" style="display:none">
      <div class="grid-container-social">
        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ubeezen/"><i class="fab fab-flag fa-facebook-square fa-10x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/ubeezen"><i class="fab fab-flag fa-instagram fa-10x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ubeezen/"><i class="fab fab-flag fa-twitter-square fa-10x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.pinterest.co.uk/ubeezen/"><i class="fab fab-flag fa-pinterest-square fa-10x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://ubeezen.tumblr.com/"><i class="fab fab-flag fa-tumblr-square fa-10x"></i></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: if you want it as background, then try `background` prop instead of `img` tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Position the `#image-left` and `#image-right` (*not the `img`*) with `position:absolute` and `width:50%` (*and one to the left, one to the right*)

So basically add

```
#image-left, #image-right{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:50%;
}
#image-left{left:0;}
#image-right{right:0;}
```

and remove the

```
#image-left img {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#image-right img {
  right: 0;
  top:0;
}
```

---

Working demo

```js
function openLink(evt, animName) {
  var i, x, tablinks;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("information");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(animName).style.display = "block";
  
}
```

```css
@font-face {
font-family:"walkway oblique ultraBold";
src:url("https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/Walkway_Oblique_UltraBold.woff?8124544898226561589") format("woff");
font-weight:normal;
font-style:normal;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  padding: 0;
  
}

.grid-container-social {
 
  grid-template-columns: auto;
  padding-left: 40px;
  padding-right: 40px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

.grid-item {
  font-family: 'walkway oblique ultraBold', arial;
  background-color: black;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 3.5vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#background img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
}
#image-left, #image-right{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  width:50%;
}
#image-left{left:0;}
#image-right{right:0;}


.background-wrap {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2vw;
}

.item1 {
  grid-column: 1 / 7;
}

.item_social {
  grid-column: 1 / 6;
}

.fab-flag:hover {
    color: #0099cc;
}
```

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container  header-space">
<div class="background-wrap"><br><br>

<div id="background"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/about_us_background.png?15676093355455950193">
  <div id="image-left"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/left_image.png?17699760671222922809"></div>
  <div id="image-right"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0019/0909/6500/files/right_image.png?17699760671222922809"></div>
</div>


  <div class="grid-container">
<div class="item1 grid-item"></div>
   

<div class="item2">
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubcrew');">
    <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub<font color="red">crew</font>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
  
  
<div class="item3">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubstory');">
  <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub<font color="red">story</font>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
  
  
<div class="item4">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubmission');">
  <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub<font color="red">mission</font>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>  
  
  
<div class="item5">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubvibe');">
  <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub<font color="red">vibe</font>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>                
 
 
<div class="item6">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubpromise');">
  <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub<font color="red">promise</font>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>            


<div class="item7">
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="openLink(event, 'ubsocial');">
  <div class="grid-item w3-hover-white">ub<font color="red">social</font>
  </div>
 </a>
</div>    

</div>


<div id="ubcrew" class="information w3-animate-opacity">
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
</div>

<div id="ubstory" class="information w3-animate-left" style="display:none">
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
</div>
  
<div id="ubmission" class="information w3-animate-top" style="display:none">
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
</div>
  
<div id="ubvibe" class="information w3-animate-right" style="display:none">
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
</div>
  
<div id="ubpromise" class="information w3-animate-bottom" style="display:none">
    <p>London is the capital city of England.</p>
    <p>It is the most populous city in the United Kingdom, with a metropolitan area of over 13 million inhabitants.</p>
</div>

<div id="ubsocial" class="information w3-animate-bottom" style="display:none">
    <div class="grid-container-social">
     <a href="https://www.facebook.com/ubeezen/"><i class="fab fab-flag fa-facebook-square fa-10x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://twitter.com/ubeezen"><i class="fab fab-flag fa-instagram fa-10x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/ubeezen/"><i class="fab fab-flag fa-twitter-square fa-10x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://www.pinterest.co.uk/ubeezen/"><i class="fab fab-flag fa-pinterest-square fa-10x"></i></a>
        <a href="https://ubeezen.tumblr.com/"><i class="fab fab-flag fa-tumblr-square fa-10x"></i></a>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gabriele, thank you so much! It works perfectly in the editor, however, when I place the code into my site, image-left & image-right take their top and left / right properties from the top and left/right of my whole page and not the div of background-image. Is there anything you could recommend to force left / right to base their properties from the background-image div? Once again, thank you for your time and guidance. Much appreciated.

Comment: @vikingtemplar you wound need to make the `#background` be `position:relative`

Comment: Works perfect! πάλι, ευχαριστώ Gabriele!